# Is there a way to access db2 databases through stored encrypted passwords using python?

Tags: python, db2, db2-luw

using python, I need to know if there is a way to access ibm db2 databases through stored encrypted passwords in client side? A feature like oracle wallet [here](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#extauth).

Comment: Depends on which __platform__ of Db2-server you mean,  Z/OS (mainframe),  i-series (as/400)  or  Linux/Unix/Windows.  Each platform offers different authentication schemes...

Comment: It's Linux/Unix/Windows

Comment: Is the Db2-LUW server running in a commercial cloud service (e.g. IBM's cloud offerings,  Amazon, Azure etc) ,  or is the Db2-server under your control?

Comment: It's under my company control but I don't have access to it, Only DBAs have. however, if the solution must need an action from them, I can contact them and see if it's feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Db2-LUW servers can be configured to support Kerberos authentication (in which case Python apps have no stored password , but rely on external cached tickets managed by Kerberos).  This is a configuration matter, implementable by DBAs , and the only programming involvement is for python to specify the authentication-method (if using a connection string), or leave that to be specified in an externally configured DSN. Corporates that use Active-Directory or an external Kerberos KDC can exploit this.

Db2-LUW servers support *local* passwordless access (when Python and the database are in the same hostname). In this case the Python app does not specify either a userid or a password when connecting to the local database, and in this case the authentication is already done by the operating system .  This is only relevant for apps that can run locally with the Db2-database.

Db2-LUW also lets you develop your own security plugins, again that is a Db2-server configuration matter, and may need Db2-client configuration also.

If neither of the above are applicable for your use-case, your options are limited to decrypting a stored-password and presenting that to the Db2-client via python connect, and the Db2-client will encrypt that password before putting it on the network provided that the Db2-server is appropriately configured. You can use an external package for the purpose of managing the passwords, but that is invisible to Db2-client, and invisible to Db2-server.

Different options can be available for cloud based services, consult your provider.